# Create Tabulator callback when Error detected

Tags: ajax, tabulator

I'm using this to call data using ajax in Tabulator:

```
$('#tablename').tabulator({
 ajaxURL: some url,
 ajaxConfig:"POST",
 ajaxParams:{...}
});
```

I have an error handler like this that will return json if there's a problem.

```
function returnError($msg) {
  $data=array();
  $data['success'] = false;
  $data['message'] = $msg;
  echo json_encode($data);
  exit;
}
```

How to I get that error from the Tabulator call, if it exists?

Not sure if standard ajax done can be appended to tabulator call? :

```
    .done(function(data) {
      if (data.success == false) {...}
    });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an ***ajaxError*** callback you can use on tabulator, that is called whenever there is a request error. you simply define it in your table definition:

```js
$('#tablename').tabulator({
    ajaxURL: some url,
    ajaxConfig:"POST",
    ajaxParams:{...}
    ajaxError:function(error){
        //error - the returned error object

        //your code goes here
    },
});
```

A full list of available callbacks can be found in the [Callback Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/callbacks#ajax)